# 2015 Kia Soul base

Tags: engine, idle, kia, soul

I will be buying a 2015 Kia Soul base with 28,000 miles on it.  Only concern is that when it is in neutral, there is roughness that I feel.....I feel a slight shaking in my right leg.  A passenger in the back seat said he also felt it.  Dealer can not find anything, and all the diagnostics check out okay. Many ideas??  Thank you very much!

Comment: In N while moving, or in N while standing still? LHD or RHD ("right leg")? Where is your right foot positioned? What do you hear? What if you push the gas pedal a bit in that situation?

Comment: I only tested neutral while still.  Right foot was on brake.  I asked dealer to push on gas pedal th next day and he said the vibration shaking greatly diminished or went away.  I asked him to check engine mounts.  Car is 1.5 hours away, will see it again n Tuesday.  He will call me Monday regarding engine mounts.  Thank you for your input and help!

Answer (score 1):

Some vehicles inherently have slight vibrations in them at idle. My '06 Chevy Silverado with a V8 in it has a slight vibration in it at idle which goes away just off idle. It's just something which can occur. Considering there's no issues on the diagnostics, I'd suggest there probably isn't much to worry about.

The great thing about a 2015 Kia Soul with only 28k miles on it ... It's still under factory bumper-to-bumper warranty until it has 5 years/60k miles on it (whichever comes first). If there really is an issue, which I doubt, the dealership should take care of it for you.